# Android Studio 2.0 fails to build sample android project out of the box

Tags: android, android-studio

I just download loaded the a brand new stable version of Android Studio.
It installs OK and ask what sort of project you'd like to open. I figured I'd open a sample project.  I selected the first one,"ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider".
Android Studio fails and tells me to look in the log file.  I see that this is the error

```
.project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

I am able to download `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip` with my browser.  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your gradle distribution URL to point to version 2.10. There are a couple ways to do this.

a) In your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, change the following line

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

b) Go to `Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and change your "Gradle home" directory to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10` or just select "Use default gradle wrapper".

Comment: Correct, I had to update the gradle wrapper to v2.10 too when I updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

when i click help> check for update> it will redirect
 http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/ << this web url. but my friends able to update without redirecting any web url. why?

Comment: It looks like your Android Studio instance is checking the canary channel for updates which will look for the newest version (alpha, beta, and rc releases). Is your friend's Android Studio settings set to only check for stable releases?